# Program skipping stages

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a Unity program, where it switches screens if the user presses ENTER.

However, whenever the user presses enter, instead of just going one screen forward, it skips all the way to the last screen.

Here is my OnGUI():

```
if (showScreen == true)
        {
        //this allows the screens to toggle
            switch (pageNum)
            {
            case 1:
                rectangle = GUI.Window(1,rectangle, Page1, "Computer");
                break;
            case 2:
                rectangle = GUI.Window(1,rectangle, Page2, "Computer");
                break;
            case 3:
                rectangle = GUI.Window(1,rectangle, Page3, "Computer");
                break;
            case 4:
                rectangle = GUI.Window(1,rectangle, Page4, "Computer");
                break;
            case 5:
                rectangle = GUI.Window(1,rectangle, Page5, "Computer");
                GUILayout.Window (2,rect2, popUp, "Warning!");
                break;
            case 6:
                rectangle = GUI.Window(1,rectangle, Page6, "Computer");
                break;
            case 7:
                rectangle = GUILayout.Window(1,rectangle, Page7, "Computer");
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

And here is where the GUIs are actually set up, and made to change:

```
void Page1(int windowID)
    {       if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            GUI.FocusControl(null);
            pageNum = 2;
        }
    }

void Page2(int windowID)
    {
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            pageNum = 3;
            GUI.FocusControl(null);
        }
    }

//continue like this for 5 more Page#(int windowID)
```

So what can I insert into these classes to make my program stop skipping? should I put a pause into these if statements too?

Comment: Can't see with the code you've posted (some more would be useful) but you are probably chaining these without marking the key event as handled. Therefore it will ripple down until it hits the last page and displays it.

Comment: I agree with Belogix, can you post the section outlining the event handler?

Comment: Actually my mistake, it looks as though Input.GetKeyDown is handling this behind the scenes. Nevertheless, it states that if the key was pressed during the Update() function, it will return true. However I'm wondering if this is propagated throughout the entire method or not. Just for comparison, can you try it with Input.GetKey()? Or, can you post your entire Update() method?

Comment: Just a thought, but this may be it. According to the API :

"...your OnGUI implementation might be called several times per frame (one call per event). For more information on GUI events see the Event reference. If the MonoBehaviour's enabled property is set to false, OnGUI() will not be called."

However you're altering the GUI each time, which may cause the behaviour where you alter the GUI in OnGUI(), which in turns spawns another call to OnGUI()

Comment: Can you try using Update() instead of OnGUI()? It sounds like altering the GUI itself from OnGUI() may be a bad practice (because it would spawn another OnGUI() event).

Comment: Were they taken out of OnGUI()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57413/discussion-between-flotolk-and-michael-di-felice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the easiest way to solve this problem is by changing how the program changes the stages. All you need to do is a boolean that changes to true once the return key has been pressed.

so just declare the boolean:

```
public class ClassName : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool wasClicked = false;
```

Then to change the states just do this:

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            wasClicked = true;
        }

        if (wasClicked)
        {
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Return))
            {
                GUI.FocusControl(null);
                pageNum = next page number;
                wasClicked = false;
            }
        }
```